# Python values of multiple lists in one list comprehension

Tags: python, list, iterator, list-comprehension

Is there any smart way to write a list comprehension over more than one list?

I know I could use a separate range list as index but this way I have to know the length (or get it separately with a `len()` function call).

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> b = range(10, 0, -1)
>>> [(a[x],b[x]) for x in range(10)]
[(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)]
```

I'd love to have something like this:

```
>>> [(a,b) for a in range(10) and b in range(10, 0, -1)]
[(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)]
```

How would you write the list comprehension? Is there a way to do this with itertools?

The range list just stand for any list and I do not necessarily want to get a tuple. there could also be a function which takes a and b as parameters. So zip is not what I want.

UPDATE: With "So zip is not what I want." I meant that I don't want `zip(range(10), range(10, 0, -1))`

Comment: Duplicate of [9184497](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184497/python-list-comprehension-function-with-arguments-in-two-lists)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your example is just:

```
zip(range(10), range(10, 0, -1))
```

More generally, you can join any set of iterables using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[func(a, d, ...) for a, b, ..., n in zip(iterable1, iterable2, ..., iterableN)]
```

Comment: The second solution is what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to consider [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) since it is better at large sequences.  Same idea, just a slightly different tool.

Comment: I think you might've meant to write `[func(a, b, ...) for a, b, ..., n in zip(iterable1, iterable2, ..., iterableN)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a function to several sequences, you need either `map` or `itertools.imap`:

```
map(lambda *x: sum(x), range(10), range(10, 0, -1), range(0,20, 2))
```

There is no need to zip unless you prefer to do your mapping in a list comprehension

Comment: That's not what he wants. Look at his second example -- he wants to `zip`. And you never need `map`, a list comprehension / generator expression can do everything it can and more.

Comment: @agf " there could also be a function which takes a and b as parameters. So zip is not what I want." You could argue that one also never needs zip, because map is available.

Comment: He wrote that before I added my second example, showing how to use a function with `zip`. Read his comment on my answer written after I added it. He meant he didn't want _just_ `zip`, not that he didn't want `zip` at all.

Comment: @agf Why zip and apply a function when you can do it in one step?

Comment: Because a list comprehension is more flexible and Pythonic. You can write the expression as a function, but you don't have to. You can use the included filtering expression rather than having to use a separate `filter` step.

Comment: @agf Not every sequence needs to be filtered.