# Two Dimensional List Python with loop

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
ask[]
timeStamp[]
```

I need to add the information in these lists into a two dimensional array.

Here is my code:

```
for item in actTime:
    rawData.append(ask[x],timeStamp[x])
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: What is `actTime` supposed to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python values of multiple lists in one list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826867/python-values-of-multiple-lists-in-one-list-comprehension)

Comment: Someone find a better duplicate about `zip`.

Comment: the timeStamp list in the loop should actually be the actTime list.  But regardless its just a list containing a time

Comment: Be precise. Show us an example of the contents of the lists before you start, and what you want the corresponding result to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
>>> pairs = zip(ask, timeStamp)
```

This will return a list of (tuple) pairs.